# Qual è il significato di "grossamente" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

Nel racconto *L'aria della sera* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Dalla finestra aperta si vedevano alberi e siepi color ruggine, le foglie sparse ai margini dei fossi, e piú in là i campi neri arati allora allora. Un merlo volava **grossamente** fra i filari spogli: la nebbia cominciava a salire e di tanto in tanto colpi di fucile venivano su dalla valle.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/grosso1/) ho trovato

> Avv. **grossaménte**, poco com. e per lo più nel sign. fig. di grossolanamente, alla buona, o superficialmente, approssimativamente: *un disegno grossamente abbozzato; una statua lignea eseguita grossamente; grossamente giudicando; mostrandogli così grossamente, come il più i mercatanti sanno fare, per quali ragioni la nostra* [fede] *era migliore che la giudaica* (Boccaccio).

Tuttavia, a me non sembra che il significato nel passaggio sopra citato sia questo. Sapreste spiegarmi il senso di "grossamente" nel brano precedente?

Comment: Secondo me intende proprio  "in modo grossolano", nel senso che era un volo irregolare e privo di grazia.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La definizione che hai trovato è secondo me pertinente; si intende proprio *"in modo grossolano"*, nel senso che era un volo irregolare e privo di grazia.